# LinkedIn - understanding User api access versus Server api access

Tags: java, linkedin-api

In the linked in throttle limits, it breaks down requests by users and by application.

E.g.

Connections:

- Application: 20k
- Per User: 1500

What does application represent at this point? How does LinkedIn know if a user is an application or a user?

Comment: @Perception Too bad you commented instead of answering. You summed it up nicely.

Comment: @siebz0r - thanks, and true enough. Converted comment -> answer.

Answer (score 1):

The breakdown:

- All requests coming to their server with your API key attached count towards your application limits.
- All requests coming to their server with your API key, for a particular user credentials, count towards that persons user limits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my use case... i simply want to go into my company's LinkedIn and see all new connections added since it was last queried. Does that count as a person's user limit?

Comment: @NicholasDiPiazza - if you are accessing it as a user through your app, with your API key, then it counts against both your user ***and*** application limits.